# Get posts made by Facebook friends only on page through GraphAPI

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api

**tl;dr: Is there a certain way to retrieve the posts made to a page, but only those made by the authenticated user's friends?**

I am working on an iOS app and I can retrieve ALL the posts made to a page using the GraphAPI method `[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"pageID/feed" andDelegate:self];` and can also retrieve the friends list of the currently authenticated user using `[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/friends" andDelegate:self];`

Is there a way to filter the first data set to get those submitted only by ids in the second data set server side (ie: through GraphAPI) or is my best option client side (my code) filtering of the results?

Comment: do you have an example of how to get all posts from a facebook page , please share it with me , thanks

Comment: @Houcine: what do you mean by all posts? If you try `[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"pageID/feed" andDelegate:self];` it will give you all that was posted to the page. Do you want something else?

Comment: yes that's what i mean , but i want an example or a tutorial to see how to parse results, and the structure of the json result, methods of delegate that i should implements etc :) thanks for your time

Comment: @Houcine I don't have any code of my own, but the [Getting Started](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/) guide got me setup and you can find everything you might need at [facbook's github](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/tree/master/sample/Hackbook)

Comment: please what permission should a use to get list of posts in a page facebook ? is it manage_pages , or read_stream or should i add something else  ? thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [FQL](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/) to accomplish this with a pretty simple query:

`SELECT post_id FROM stream WHERE source_id = PAGEID AND actor_id IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())`

The second part of this query in parenthesis is selecting a list of user IDs of the current users friends (determined by the access token used to query) and then this UID list is being used to filter the first part of the query which selects a list of post_ids which are posted to a particular page ID (make sure to substitute the placeholder for your own Page ID).

This will give you just a list of Post IDs, however the [stream table documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/) will show you more of the fields that you can select.

Note that FQL might be considered a separate API from the Graph API, however it can actually very simply be run through the Graph API, as shown in [this blog post](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/579/).